# Algebraic steps to translate this expression into the pictured form?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

[image]

What are the intermediate steps to arrive at the second form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just considering the numerators,

$$\begin{eqnarray*}
n(n+1)(2n+1)+6(n+1)^2 &=& (n+1)n(2n+1)+6(n+1)(n+1)\\
                      &=& (n+1)\bigl[n(2n+1) + 6(n+1)\bigr]\\
                      &=& (n+1)(2n^2+ n + 6n+6)
\end{eqnarray*}$$

Comment: What happened to the extra n+1 that was a part of n+1^2 ?

Comment: It first got split into $(n+1)(n+1)$ and then factored out toward the front.

Comment: Ah I see now more clearly after the edit you made. Man, that is very tricky!  Thanks so much!  I think your answer helped clarify this for me! :)

Answer (score 0):

Let's just look at the numerator (since the denominator hasn't changed). We start with:

$$n(n+1)(2n+1)+6(n+1)^2=(n+1)((2n+1)n+6(n+1))$$
$$(n+1)((2n+1)n+6(n+1))=(n+1)((2n^2+n)+(6n+6))$$
$$(n+1)((2n^2+n)+(6n+6))=(n+1)(2n^2+7n+6)$$

And we see that the final expression is equivalent to the one you ended with.

Comment: Your left side of your second line seems to have lost an $n$.

Comment: Good catch. Fixed.